# $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if its graph is compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This question may be asked before under different formulation, the original problem is Chapter 4, Exercise 7 of Rudin's text: *The Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

**Problem:**
If $f$ is defined on $E$, the *graph* is the set of points $(x, f(x))$, for $x \in E$.

Suppose $E$ is compact, and prove that $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if its graph is compact.

**My Attempt:** Let $\Gamma(f) = \{(x, f(x)): x \in E\} \subset E \times \mathbb{R}^1$. I was trying to define a function $F: E \rightarrow E \times \mathbb{R}^1$ by $F(x) = (x, f(x))$ and show $F$ is continuous on $E$. Since $E$ is compact, it follows that $F(E) = \Gamma(f)$ is compact.

For the converse, the earlier thread 
[A real function on a compact set is continuous if and only if its graph is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972251/a-real-function-on-a-compact-set-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-its-graph-is-compa) stated that the projection function $\pi$ is continuous on $E \times \mathbb{R}^1$.

My question is: without knowing any specific metric on $E$ or on $E \times \mathbb{R}^1$, it looks hard to me to show that $F$ and $\pi$ aforementioned are continuous. Since the condition doesn't give any information about what I concern, how should I proceed?

Comment: We can get a metric on this product by defining an induced metric on the product of metric spaces.  For example, given $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, it is common to define the induced metric on $X \times Y$ by
$$
d_{X \times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = 
d_X(x_1,x_2) + d_Y(y_1,y_2)
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for your reply. I knew we might can do so, but I am actually trying to avoid such "subjective" proof. I am wondering is there any "objective" proof that without imposing any metric by ourselves? I think the existence of $d_X$ is fine, the annoying part is can we proceed without giving any specific metric form on $d_{X \times \mathbb{R}^1}$?

Comment: the problem is that you have to say what it means for $\Gamma(f)$ to be compact, for which we need some kind of topology on $E \times \Bbb R$.  If you're not going to get this topology using a "subjective" choice of metric on the product, then perhaps you should do so using the definition of the product topology, ignoring the underlying metrics altogether.

Comment: @Zhanxiong the metric .@Omnomnomnom defined induces the product topology, as there are only finitely many factors. So it isn't "subjective". Whatever that in this context might mean.

Comment: So literally, we can use any metric on $E \times \mathbb{R}^1$, such as $d_{E \times \mathbb{R}^1}((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = \max(d_E(x_1, x_2), |y_1 - y_2|)$, right? What I mean by "subjective" is like this --- the proof details depend on the specification of the metric on $E \times \mathbb{R}^1$, which I understand is acceptable but not that perfect...

Comment: @Zhanxiong it really depends on the topology, and each of these metrics produces the same topology

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I have very limited knowledge on  topological space, so I will just go with picking up any fixed metric on $E \times \mathbb{R}^1$ and satisfy myself. Many thanks to your patience.

Comment: @Zhanxiong it's probably the expected method, anyway. Glad to help.

Comment: This is obviously false for general $E$. Consider as an example  $E$ the Sierpinski space. Then every graph is compqct as it is finite, but not every function is continuous.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose that $f$ is continuous, and define $F(x):=(x,f(x))\subset E\times\mathbb R$. Fix $x\in E$ and consider a sequence $(x_n)\subset E$ converging to $x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and hence $F(x_n)=(x_n,f(x_n))\to(x,f(x))=F(x)$, which shows that $F$ is continuous. Now your argument works fine, since now $\Gamma(f)=F(E)$ is compact.

For the converse assume that $\Gamma(f)=F(E)$ is compact. Fix $x\in E$ and a sequence $(x_n)\subset E$ converging to $x$. Assume that $(x_n,f(x_n))$ does not converge to $(x,f(x))$. Since $\Gamma(f)$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})$ that converges in $\Gamma(f)$ to some $(x',y)\neq(x,f(x))$. But since $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then so does $(x_{n_k})$ (because it's a subsequence), which implies $x'=x$. But since $(x',y)\in\Gamma(f)$, we must have $y=f(x')=f(x)$ and consequently $(x',y)=(x,f(x))$, a contradiction. This shows that $(x_n,f(x_n))\to(x,f(x))$; in particular, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, which proves that $f$ is continuous at $x$ (and that $F$ is continuous at $x$ as well).

Comment: Does this generalize ? If $E$ is any compact space and $D$ is any space, is it true that $f:E\to D$ is continuous iff the graph of $f$ is compact?......+1

Comment: There's no contradiction on "$(x_n,f(x_n)) \not\rightarrow (x,f(x))$ but $(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})) \rightarrow (x,f(x))$". That's something you could expect from a discontinuous function (which is your assumption):
Let $f = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$, and let $(x_n)_n \subset [0,1]$ be the sequence
\begin{align*}
&x_{2n-1} = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n} \\
&x_{2n} = 1 
\end{align*}
Then, $x_n \rightarrow 1$, $(x_{2n},f(x_{2n})) \rightarrow (1,1)$, but $(x_n, f(x_n)) \not\rightarrow (1,1)$

Comment: I also assumed that the graph of $f$ is compact, which is not true for your example. So I don't see any problem...