# Prove that if $f$ is a bounded continuous function then $G$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact topological space. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R$. Define $G(f)=\{(x,f(x)):\,x\in X\}$.

Prove that if $f$ is a bounded continuous function then $G$ is compact.

Since $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff then $G(f)$ is closed.
Now $G(f)\subset X\times f(X)$ which is compact since $X$ is so. Since every closed subset of a compact space is compact so $G(f)$ is compact.

Is this proof correct? Where is the hypothesis $f$ is bounded needed?

Comment: The hard part is to show what you stated without proof -- that $G(f)$ is closed.

Comment: $X\times f(X)$ is compact being product of two compact sets $X$ and $f(X)$(image of compact set under a continuous map). $G(f)$ is a closed subset of $X\times f(X)$.

Comment: is $X$ Hausdorff? Also, who is $E$ in the definition of $G(f)$?

Comment: @BigM: And why is $G(f)$ closed? This is the mistake that everybody does here.

Comment: I assumed he/she knew how to show that the graph of a continuous function is closed.

Comment: @BigM: The graph of a continuous function is not always closed, that's what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: agreed. Hausdorffness is needed.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, it is automatically bounded. So boundedness is superfluous.

Comment: This question seems closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972251/a-real-function-on-a-compact-set-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-its-graph-is-compa

Comment: @BigM;No Hausdorffness needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine. The hypothesis "$f$ is bounded" is not needed, but that is fine. It is automatically true, as $f[X]$, being a compact subsets of $\mathbf R$ is bounded for any continuous $f$.

Comment: Like MPW commented, it might not come without saying that $G(f)$ is closed. Easy or not, this isn't immediate (in my opinion).

Comment: The proof is not fine since it is not explained why $G(f)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

We must assume $X$ to be Hausdorff, otherwise I believe that your statement is false.

Since $X$ is compact and $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, it follows that $f$ is closed, therefore $f(X)$ is closed (not $G(f)$ as you write). Since $f$ is continuous on a bounded space, it is bounded (no need to assume it!), therefore $f(X)$ (being closed) is compact. Therefore, $X \times f(X)$ is compact. The map $X \ni x \mapsto (x, f(x)) \in X \times f(X) \subseteq X \times \Bbb R$ is closed, so its image will be a closed subset of the compact space $X \times f(X)$, therefore compact itself.

Note that you have used [the closed map lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#Open_and_closed_mapping_theorems) twice: if $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, $X$ is compact and $Y$ Hausdorff, then $f$ is a closed map (i.e. the image of any closed subset is closed).

Comment: I don't know why you are saying so but definitely you can have a look into the proof of **Every closed subspace of Compact space is compact**

Comment: Let $U_\alpha $ be an open cover of $Y$ then $X=(X\setminus Y) \cup (\cup Y_\alpha) $ is an open cover of $X$ Then...

Comment: @Amartya: As you state it, your open cover argument is wrong: you must begin with an arbitrary open cover of $X$, not with one of $Y$.

Comment: @Amartya: In any case, you are right when you say that Hausdorff-ness is not needed in order for a closed subset to be compact. I was thinking of "a compact set is closed", which is true only in Hausdorff spaces. Still, you need $X$ to be Hausdorff in order to apply the closed map lemma for $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$, which shows that your statement was doubly wrong: it included a useless hypothesis (the boundedness of $f$) and it omitted an essential one ($X$ being Hausdorff). I think that with this we've clarified it.

Comment: you are wrong again..i want to prove $Y$ compact;so it's necessary to start with an open cover of Y

Comment: closed subspace Y of compact space X is compact...Please have a go through it;

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to find that if $f:X\to Y $ is continuous and $Y$ is Hausdorff then $G(f)$ is closed;Please try to prove it ;it will be of help to you;thank you